# Manipulate and sort the term names of a product attribute in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I'm trying to sort names in alphabetical order after a reverse array.

It's a code done for ordering last name/first name in right order.
A few bugs, (like with names with middle names) but it works except the sorting.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $terms = get_terms( 'pa_artist' );
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
         echo '<ul class="artists">';
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $array = explode(" ", $term->name);
            if ($array[3]) { 
                $array[3] = strtoupper($array[3]);
                $array[3] = "<strong>".$array[3]."</strong>";
            }
            elseif ($array[2]) { 
                $array[2] = strtoupper($array[2]);
                $array[2] = "<strong>".$array[2]."</strong>";
            } elseif ($array[1]) { 
                $array[1] = strtoupper($array[1]);
                $array[1] = "<strong>".$array[1]."</strong>";
            } else { 
                $array[0] = strtoupper($array[0]);
                $array[0] = "<strong>".$array[0]."</strong>";
            } 
            $rarray = array_reverse($array);
           sort($rarray); 
            echo '<li><a href="' .get_term_link( $term ). '" title="' . sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $term->name ) . '">' . implode(" ", $rarray) . '</a></li>';
        }
     echo '</ul>';
 }
```

For now the names are ordered as if the reverse was never done.

Some examples, at first it showed like this:

```
Auguste Renoir
Pablo Picasso
Paul Gauguin
```

After the reverse and If strings, it's like this:

```
RENOIR Auguste
PICASSO Pablo
GAUGUIN Paul
```

When i need it:

```
GAUGUIN Paul
PICASSO Pablo
RENOIR Auguste
```

I tried every sort fonction, can't make it work… I can't find a way to sort after a reverse array, is it even possible?

It's for a list of names builded with attributes on wordpress/woocommerce.

I already asked that question, got answers that didn't work unfortunately…

There is Something like 150 names that needs ordering.

I'm willing to pay for this, but no-one is interested because it doesn't require much time so won't pay much! (Only got request to redo the whole website…)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$terms = get_terms( [ 'taxonomy' => 'pa_artist', 'hide_empty' => false ] );

$names_html = $terms_data = [];

if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    // 1st Loop: Loop through the terms
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        $fragments = explode( ' ', $term->name );

        if( sizeof($fragments) > 1 ) {
            // Manipulate and format the term name
            $fragment = '<strong>' . strtoupper($fragments[1]) .'</strong>';
            $new_term = $fragment . ' ' . $fragments[0];

            // 1st array: We set each formatted term name
            $names_html[] = $new_term;

            // 2nd array: We set the related data as the Url and the original term name
            $terms_data[$new_term] = array(
                'link' => get_term_link( $term ),
                'name' => $term->name,
            );
        }
    }
    // Sort the formatted term names
    sort($names_html);

    // Output
    echo '<ul class="artists">';

    // 2nd Loop: Loop through the sorted formatted term names
    foreach ( $names_html as $name_html ) {
        $link  = $terms_data[$name_html]['link'];
        $title = sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $terms_data[$name_html]['name'] );

        echo '<li><a href="' . $link . '" title="' . $title . '">' . $name_html . '</a></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Tested and works.

[image]